# CRM 2011 - New Appointment from Case defaults Required Attendees to Account

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

When I create a new appointment from the context of a saved incident it defaults the "Required Attendees" field to the incident's account. I want it to default to blank or the current user. (To create the appointment I used the navigation pane on the incident to view related activities then use the ribbon button add new activity.)

Where can I control that behaviour?

I tried looking at the entity mappings but it appears there isn't a "mappable" relationship for the "RequiredAttendees" field. (I checked as per the instructions here: http://rc.crm.dynamics.com/rc/2011/en-us/on-prem/5.0/help/ui_cust_Mapping.htm) Have I missed something or is this a hardcoded CRM-ism?

Going forward do I have any options to modify this? I suppose I could do javascript on form load but I'd prefer this be configurable inside CRM without touching javascript.

Comment: I have since learned that you can only map non-custom attributes, and given that required attendees is a non-standard field I assume it will not be in the list for the same reason non-custom attributes are: the entity mappings aren't a robust feature... it is assumed some javascript will be required it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that best solution is to use onLoad javascript. Just check that Appointment is created from Incident form. (In Url - Type=112)

You can rewrite ribbon button on Incident form to open new window with URL

```
http://myCRM/myOrg/main.aspx?etc=4201&extraqs=%3fcontactInfo%3d%26etc%3d4201%26pId%3d%257bB8C55089-26D7-E111-93D4-005056986118%257d%26pName%3dCaseName%26pType%3d112%26pagemode%3diframe%26preloadcache%3d1346939630259&pagetype=entityrecord
```

So just exclude:

```
partyaddressused%3d%26
partyid%3d%257bA9D02C74-26D7-E111-93D4-05056986118%257d%26partyname%3dAdministrator%2540crm.local%26
partytype%3d2%26
```

This part of url contains data related to activity party ('required' field).

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to look at the url. I am still looking to see if anyone knows if I can configure this inside of CRM without javascript.

Comment: looks like no is the answer to my comment. Marking as answer.